# Unable to tabulate data read in from file

Tags: python, file, tabular

My code in fruitveggielist.py should read the file and print to table. I am using `tabulate`

`fruit.txt`

```
corn, apple
lettuce, grapes
pepper, melon
```

However should be shown in table with headers `veggie fruit`.

Code so far:

```
from tabulate import tabulate
filepath = 'fruit.txt'
with open(filepath) as fp:
   line = fp.readline()

   while line:
           print tabulate("{}".format(line.strip()), headers=['Veggie', 'Fruit'])
           line = fp.readline()
```

Print-

```
Veggie
--------
c
o
r
n
,

a
p
p
l
e
```

etc,etc...

How would I use tabulate or another table formater to correctly print fruit.txt to a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the easiest way to do this is to put your data inside a nested list.

As you're doing it now, strings are treated as iterables, so each character is treated as a separate item and given its own row. You also end up putting headers over each row of data read in.

As mentioned before, the best way to solve this would be to put everything into a list and call the function *once*. Each pair should be a separate record.

```
from tabulate import tabulate

data = []
with open('fruit.txt') as f:
     for line in f:
        data.append(list(map(str.strip, line.split(','))))
```

```
print(tabulate(data, tablefmt='grid', headers=('veggie', 'fruit')))

+----------+---------+
| veggie   | fruit   |
+==========+=========+
| corn     | apple   |
+----------+---------+
| lettuce  | grapes  |
+----------+---------+
| pepper   | melon   |
+----------+---------+
```

Comment: @BenjaminJones You're welcome. Do consider marking the answer accepted, if  it was useful for you. Thanks.

Comment: Yes it was very useful!